# Combine elastic search range query with a filter to exclude null values on other field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a Kibana report where I set a `not emptyIdOrParentId: null` filter, in addition to the default date query.  When I try to do this query from the "dev tools" I have no chance replicating this simple behaviour. I have tried endless combinations of embedding inside the json tree, and my latest attempt is this:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": 1606694400000,
              "lt": 1906299110458
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "emptyIdOrParentId"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
...
```

But it keeps returning buckets with `emptyIdOrParentId: null`.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more `query_string` query just to make sure:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": 1606694400000,
              "lt": 1906299110458,
              "format": "epoch_millis"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "emptyIdOrParentId"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "_exists_:emptyIdOrParentId AND NOT emptyIdOrParentId:null"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but your `exists` query *should* already exclude all null `emptyIdOrParentIds`. Can you share the docs that are returned but shouldn't be?

Comment: I’ll test it out.  I will also try to take out a sample value for the bucket that contains the null-value.